# Checking for value of the switch ui widget if it is turned on

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiswitch

**Initializations**

```
    Switch notifswitch;


    Switch notifswitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch);
```

**Firebase reference**

```
      myrefNotif =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
      getReference("Questions").child(questionId).child("Notif");
```

**Code:**

```
myrefNotif.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            notifswitch.setChecked(true); // << ERROR ORIGIN
        } 
        else {
            notifswitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {   }
});
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
>   (Directory)=>>>>QuestionProfile$3.onDataChange

Comment: Did you know that name of your `notifswtich` has a typo? Maybe check that you don't use "proper" name in UI?

Comment: It looks like your `notifswtich` field is never initialized. It's hard to say from the current code where that initialization is supposed to happen, but the error message makes it clear that it hasn't been initialized. To allow us to better help, try to share the [minimal **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Typically this will include some Android lifecycle methods (`onCreate`, `onStart`) where you initialize `notifswtich`, and then the lifecycle method where you call `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: @Vennefor Are you sure you have intilisez the `notifswtich` object? Please responde with @.

Comment: Ok i will try to look at my initializations and if doesnt work ill respond with the minimal complete set of codes thank you..

Comment: No it wasnt Typo im sorry

Comment: Here is the minimal codes for notif Switch i just edited it

Comment: @AlexMamo Ok i will try to respond with this I did the initializations right

Comment: @Vennefor And in which place are you initializing the switch? Please add more relevand code.

Comment: @AlexMamo I already fixed it by putting it in Oncreate method rather than Onstart and fixing my condition in the onDatachange it might get null value because my condition was wrong thanks guys! <3